# converts varchar to int while i am inserting to an sql table

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I have this table, which i have named Users, and whenever the user is using the sign up form i want to insert to the Users.table all the credentials he enters. The problem is that, somehow, the database is trying to convert the Username(column) from varchar to int. This is my insert Query :

```
string Query = "Insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, Username,
                Password, Role, Email, Class) values('" + txtfn.Text + "',
                '" + txtsn.Text + "','" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "',
                '" + cbRole.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + cbClass.Text + "')";
```

[The error that pops-ups everytime a user is trying to sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77gpI.png)

How can i prevent this conversion from happening or is any other way to deal with this error?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement for the Users table?

Comment: What is the datatype of `Username` column? What is the value of `txtUsername.Text` ?

Comment: Beware of SQL Injection! Death! Use ADO.NET parameters.

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid SQL Injection and get rid of this errors.

Comment: @VigneshKumar
the datatype of username column is VARCHAR[50]
the txtUsername.Text is the username that the user choose to have inside the application, so it's a string

Comment: Script out the `CREATE TABLE` and add it to your question.

Comment: The error says it's converting the varchar value 'USERNAME' to int, that's the actual value, not the name of the column.

Comment: Guys I solved it thanks to @MartinSmith. The sql database by default sets for primary key an integer. I wanted my primary key to be the Username, but i forgot to change its datatype to varchar. Sorry for the bothering and thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use SQL parameters and specify the types. Which is safier and more precise and also handle conversions for some types (such as DateTime):

```
string Query = "Insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, Username, "
            + " Password, Role, Email, Class) "
            + " values(@fn, @sm, @user, @ps, @role, @email, @class)";

SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlconnection);

// change the types to match SQL Column data types
// I set all as Nvarchar as a sample
var fnParma = new SqlParameter("@fn", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var smParma = new SqlParameter("@sm", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var userParma = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var psParma = new SqlParameter("@ps", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var roleParma = new SqlParameter("@role", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var emailParma = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
var classParma = new SqlParameter("@class", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

// Here set each value by converting it to the specified type.

fnParma.Value = txtfn.Text;
smParma.Value = txtsn.Text;
// Continue for all the params. If you have int column use Int32.Parse(Text);

sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `username` column in sql table expects integer and here you are passing string. So change the `username` column datatype to `varchar` in your table. It will work fine. Hope it is clear.

Comment: did you check the exception, first its sqlexception second it fails when try to convert user name to int. it means it is expecting integer and trying to convert it and failing.

Comment: that is what I am saying looking at the error that column is expecting integer and here what value he is passing varchar.

Comment: If he posts the create table script, It will be easier for us to give a concrete statement about the problem.